# jQuery Datatables - Column Header (<th>) text is overlapping

Tags: css, datatables

I dont know why the text is overlapping.
Here's the screenshot showing the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D0gj.png
As you can see the column header 'Subcontratada' is overlapping.
What's the problem with my code?

Here's my CSS code:

---

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * DataTables display
 */
table.display {
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

table.display thead th {
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    * cursor: hand;
}
```

---

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico" />

        <title>DataTables Editor example</title>
        <style class="include" type="text/css">
            @import "support/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css";
            @import "support/bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css";
            @import "css/customTable.css";
        </style>

        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../media/js/dataTables.editor.js"></script>

        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.editor.bootstrap.js"></script>

        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="dt_example">
        <div id="mContainer" style="border: red 4px dashed;width:1200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
            <div id="demo"  style="border: blue 4px dashed;width:1200px;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered display" id="example"">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Data</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Tema</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">V&iacute;nculo</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Empresa</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Subcontratada</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">NDP</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">CH</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">HHT</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Ger&ecirc;ncia</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Área Solicitante</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">CC</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Rateio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know why but you can solve this problem by giving space between name

```
<th style="text-align: center;">Sub contratada</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser will not break text in the middle of a word. You need to manually insert a line break using `<br />` if you want it to break in the middle of the word. Or maybe decrease the font size in that column header.

Answer (score 0):

**some options**

Scroll - horizontal:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html

or

Responsive
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/

*ps: this helped me!*